# Button is not clickable or focusable

Tags: android

I have created a button in my screen's XML like this:

```
   <Button android:text="Lets Get Started"        

          android:background="@drawable/btnbg"  
          android:id="@+id/btn_nav_let_strtd"android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="35px" 
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_getstart">
           </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

set click listenrss

```
private LinearLayout ll_get_started;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.navigation);
btn_nav_lets_get_strtd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_let_strtd); 

btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setClickable(true);

}
private void setOnclickListeners() {
btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("clicked");
    Toast.makeText(NavigationScreen.this, "fgd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

But when I try to click this button, it is neither clickable nor focusable. How do I set it as clickable?

I am now using a statelist drawable, but it sets the background when focused or clicked. I want to set a permanent background to this button.

And the drawable is not a bitmap, it is a statlist drawable btnbg. XML is below:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:constantSize="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:variablePadding="true" >
    <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/nav_blue_bar"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    />
```

Comment: Did you set an on-click listener for the button?

Comment: What is your background, @drawable/nav_blue_bar?  It should be a ColorStateList resource with different values for the focused, pressed, and default states.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should add a listener to listen the clic event on your button like this :

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

//add the listener to your Button 
btn.addOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v ){

        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "the button is clicked ...", 3000).show();

    }
});
```