# Button is not clickable?

Tags: android

I have created a button in my screen's xml like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bg">


       <Button android:text="Lets Get Started"        

              android:background="@drawable/btnbg"  
              android:id="@+id/btn_nav_let_strtd"android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="35px" 
               android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow"
               android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nav_getstart">
               </Button>
```

set click listenrss

public class NavigationScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private Button btn_nav_lets_get_strtd;

```
private LinearLayout ll_get_started;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation);
    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_let_strtd); 


    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setClickable(true);




}
private void setOnclickListeners() {
    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("clicked");
           Toast.makeText(NavigationScreen.this, "fgd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });



}
```

}

but when i try to click this button it is not clickable not focusable .. how do i set it as clickable ???

and the drawable is not a bitmap it  is a statlist drawable
   btnbg.xmlis here

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:constantSize="true"
android:dither="true"
android:variablePadding="true" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/nav_blue_bar"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    />
```

any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: plz add your full code of xml and class file

Comment: seeing as you didn't respond the last time people tried to help you on this exact question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389308/button-is-not-clickable-or-focusable) I don't think it makes sense for you to dupe it here.

Answer (score 1):

look at your Code , **you didn't call** the method `setOnClickListeners()` in your method `onCreate()` !! ,

to fixe your problem , you should call your method like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation);
    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_let_strtd); 


    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setClickable(true);//here you don't need to call this method because the button is clickable by default

//call your method setOnClickListeners() here 
setOnClickListeners();




}
private void setOnclickListeners() {
    btn_nav_lets_get_strtd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           System.out.println("clicked");
           Toast.makeText(NavigationScreen.this, "fgd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
```